# Connect to Oracle database through Azure data factory

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-data-factory

I have to get data from a Oracle database through ADF into ADLS. I have a linked service which connects to the Oracle database(type : Oracle).
I am actually not able to create the dataset for this linked service as there is no option for a Oracle dataset creation in the ADF.

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click Dataset > New Dataset, you should see this below. If you do not, you should open an Azure ticket to see if there is something wrong with your browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you click on Dataset | New from your ADF UI, you can then type in "Oracle" in the dataset search bar to find the Oracle connector.

Comment: I actually tried that. but could not find any connector named "oracle". in the database section, there are only SQL server and  sql server managed instance available options.